# Disposable resources in library code

Tags: c#, .net, theory, idisposable

Imagine you're writing a library. Say, this library is going to be used in 24/7 server application. There are some unmaneged resourses, wrapped in your public API, so you implement Disposable pattern( you may even implement finalizers)

Normally, you would use `using` statement to free the unmanaged resources. But you are writing just a library, not a final application. What if another programmer 'forgotten' to call `Dispose()`? You are going to get resource leak in your lib!
We could rely on finalizers, but there is no guarantee that a finalizer would ever been [called](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx).
So, is there a way to guarantee that somehow the unmanaged resources would be freed? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution except documenting your classes. Write explicitly in your documentation how your classes are meant to be used (i.e. they are meant to be disposed at the earliest possible time, possibly with `using`, or with an explicit call to `Dispose`).

You are no more responsible for memory leaks if your consumer does not properly dispose its object than industrials are responsible for the pollution if people trash their garbage in the wild.

Comment: Thx for answer. nice metaphor!

Answer (score 1):

You could hope that the server application has code analysis rule [CA2213: Disposable fields should be disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182328.aspx) enabled.

Otherwise I don't know if there is a way to guarantee that they call your Dispose() method.

Comment: This kinda might help. Static analysis rules:) But I thought of programmable solution to this problem.